# HTML & CSS - Full Screen Image

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, web

I'm working on a website where I want an **image** to straight away take up the screen. I want to make it take up the available screen but *when you begin to scroll down* I want a **div** to appear with the text and information. I do not mind if only some of the image is showing (like the bottom is slightly missing). I can do it, but it doesn't work on other **resolutions**.

I would rather **not** use javascript but if it is the only way I don't mind.

**NEW** another way of explaining what I'm trying to do is, I want the margin from the top  of a div relative to the screen, so that on all screens the div appears as soon as you begin to move down the page.

Comment: Can you please show you code effort

Comment: can you create a fiddle of what you have tried so far??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking about Parallax.

Explore a bit on Parallax in Wiki and see some [samples here](http://www.awwwards.com/30-great-websites-with-parallax-scrolling.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="imageDiv"></div>
  <div class="contentDiv">
   <h1>This is heading</h1>
   <p>This is Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </body>
<html>
```

CSS

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.imageDiv{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:url(http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Swing-02124.jpg) no-repeat top center #000;
}
```

No jquery has used

Comment: Didn't work, the height goes to 100%. But not to 100% of the screen

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to build a parallax website. Its possible to do this with only css and no java script. If you check you Keith Clark's blog post it should give you a good idea. http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

```
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.parallax__layer--back {
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
}


<div class="parallax">
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```